# Jsp is not invoking default java functions

Tags: jsp, java-8, tomcat8

I have jsp where I am trying to invoke default JAVA functions like toString, name() etc..

Source Object -> Function which is not working

```
 Long         ->  toString()
 Enum         ->  name()
 Locale       ->  displayName()
```

Sample JSP Codes

```
<div><s:select name="displayLocale" list="locales" listValue="displayName" emptyOption="false" /></div>
```

Corresponding Java Action class:

```
public List<Locale> getLocales()
  {
    List<Locale> locales = localeDAO.getLocales();
    Collections.sort( locales, new LocaleComparator() );
    return locales;
  }
```

Same way I am facing issues for other types too..

Environment: JSP 2.0, Tomcat 8, Java 8

Can anyone help me is there anything else i need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  I'd forgotten, but the jstl only has access to properties that follow the javabean standard, which is why locales  is accessible to you. So you only have access to methods like this getFoo, getBaz, setFoo, and setBaz  as "foo" and "baz".

It seems that it is possible to access a static method in a class by using a custom tag library: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073435/java-web-development/call-javabean-methods-from-jsp-2-0-pages.html  That just seems like WAY too many hoops to jump through just to call a method on an object. I'd forgotten just how labor intensive web development used to me.

You might consider some other more modern templating like http://www.thymeleaf.org/

Comment: Even I am NOT able to access displayName from locale even though, java Locale object has getDisplayName.